# Display one span at a time using css

Tags: html, css

I've a html page with two span tag's which displays the same content but nested in a div with different class name:

```html
<div class='class1'>
  <span class='test-icon'>1</span>
</div>

<div class='class2'>
  <span class='test-icon'>2</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way i can show only one `<span>` at a time *based on the nested class*, e.g. i've tried with the `div.class1 span.test-icon {display: none}`but it hides both.

Comment: `div.class1 span.test-icon {display:none;}` can't hide both, unless `div.class2` is inside `div.class1`

Comment: you didn't close your span correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwe2bLye/

Comment: corrected mate @jvecsei

Comment: @supercool then it should work as you can see at my jsfiddle ;)

Comment: dam it's working now not before . sorry mates .

Comment: @supercool Glad it works now. If you want to select one of the spans if they're inside one div, you can do that like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwe2bLye/1/). All 3 methods in the css work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close your span tags!

Here you are:

```css
.class1  .test-icon{
  display: none;
 }

/*.class2  .test-icon{
  display: none;
 }*/
```

```html
<div class='class1'>
<span class='test-icon'>Hola</span>
</div>

<div class='class2'>
<span class='test-icon'>Adios</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You copied the faulty html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as it should:

```css
div.class1 span.test-icon {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class='class1'>
<span class='test-icon'>Span 1</span>
</div>

<div class='class2'>
<span class='test-icon'>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You copied the faulty html

Comment: I did actually completelymiss the html error. I copied the code and it worked, so I didn't even check the html syntax. Thank for noticing!